# Как вывести несколько дат в bootstrap-datepicker?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, datepicker

[https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker](https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=4&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox)

datepicker указал по ссылке сверху
мне нужно вывести список дат от и до.
например что бы в календаре была дата
от 19.11.2016 до 25.11.2016
и так несколько таких позиций
от 19.11.2016 до 25.11.2016
от 28.11.2016 до 03.12.2016
в одном календаре

```js
 $('.datepicker').datepicker({
 language: "ru"
 });
 });



<div class="input-group  datepicker" data-date="25.11.2016"></div>
<input type="hidden">
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
$('.datepicker1, .datepicker2').datepicker({
    language: "ru"
 });

<div class="input-group  datepicker1" data-date="10.11.2016"></div>
<div class="input-group  datepicker2" data-date="25.11.2016"></div>
```

Comment: неа не хочет, может есть какое то решение с помощью другого календаря не знаете?